# oozie workflow containg fork/ join with decesion node

Tags: oozie-workflow

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.5" name="shell-wf">


       <start to="fork_node" />

       <fork name = "fork_node">
          <path start = "query1"/>
          <path start = "query2"/>
       </fork>

       <action name="query1">
          <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
             <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
             <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
             <configuration>
                <property>
                   <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                   <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
             </configuration>
             <exec>oozie.sh</exec>
             <file>oozie.sh#oozie.sh</file>
             <capture-output />
          </shell>
          <ok to="join_node" />
          <error to="postgre"/>
       </action>

       <action name="query2">
          <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
             <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
             <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
             <configuration>
                <property>
                   <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                   <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
             </configuration>
             <exec>oozie2.sh</exec>
             <file>oozie2.sh#oozie2.sh</file>
             <capture-output />
          </shell>
          <ok to="join_node" />
          <error to="postgre" />
       </action>

       <join name = "join_node" to = "postgre"/>

          <action name="postgre">
          <shell xmlns="uri:oozie:shell-action:0.1">
             <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
             <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
             <configuration>
                <property>
                   <name>mapred.job.queue.name</name>
                   <value>${queueName}</value>
                </property>
             </configuration>
             <exec>oozie3.sh</exec>
             <file>oozie3.sh#oozie3.sh</file>
             <capture-output />
          </shell>
          <ok to="decesion-node" />
          <error to="fail" />
       </action>

       <decision name="decesion-node">
            <switch>
                <case to="end">
                  ${wf:lastErrorNode()} eq ""
                </case>
                <default to="fail"/>
            </switch>
        </decision>


        <kill name="fail">
          <message>Action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}  ]</message>
       </kill>
       <end name="end" />
    </workflow-app>
```

Getting below error while trying to run the above workflow.xml Invalid transition from node [decesion-node] to node [end] -- nodes of type 'end' are not allowed within Fork/Join
My use case is to always transit to the postgre action irrespective of job is getting killed or success, once the postre action is executed, if any action has failed it should go to kill node otherwise to end node.

Answer (score 0):

when u run 2 MR code in fork join it needs availability of MR in ur cluster. so when u run more than 2 MR code it may fail in fork and join.
can u share ur *.sh files or u can check if u r executing normal shell commands from u .sh file or executing any MR code from shell file.

so if u r running MR code than try to increase MR in ur cluster

thanks , happy learning :D

Comment: Thanks, but as I changed my case statement to fail from end it is working. .sh file just have one echo command.

Comment: if your .sh file contains only shell commands then its not an issue with availability of MR.
it might be issue with the "case statement"
Thanks :)